# Session: Configured driver 'cookie' was not found - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I got this error:

```
Type: UnexpectedValueException

Message: Session: Configured driver 'cookie' was not found. Aborting.
```

config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver']          = 'cookie';
$config['sess_valid_drivers']    = array();
$config['sess_cookie_name']    = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 68400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']   = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']      = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']   = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 68500;
$config['sess_save_path']       = '/';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
```

what is my wrong?

Comment: Some of those config items seem to be from old versions of CI. For instance, `$config['sess_expire_on_close']` is not used after v3. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

By default, codeigniter 3 only provide this drivers :

```
files
database
redis
memcached
```

And `files` driver are used by default. On your setting you are selecting `cookie` which will be treated as a custom driver, which you should provide that custom library.